# Grep only Domain name in HTML

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a html file i want domain name's to be extracted from.

```
www.this_i_dont_want.com
<div class="message" 

garbage..
garbage...

www.hotmail.com
hotmail.com
hotmail.com/blah.php
http://www.hotmail.com/a.php?fdas
www. hotmail. com/a.php
hotmail . com
garbage....
                </div>
```

I want only "hotmail.com" extracted from this example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which `hotmail.com` did you want to extract?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Probably the single string `hotmail.com` from each line.

Answer (score 1):

This would match three `hotmail.com` string. Look behind is used here,

```
grep -oP '(?<=www\.)\s?[^\/]*' file
```

Example:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=www\.)\s?[^\/]*' file
hotmail.com
hotmail.com
 hotmail. com
```

OR

This matches any character before  `.com` zero or more times upto a literal dot appears on the input,

```
$ grep -oP '[^\.]*\.com' file
hotmail.com
hotmail.com
hotmail.com
hotmail.com
```

I think this is the command you looking for because it matches only `hotmail.com`. No spaces before or after the string `hotmail.com`

Comment: thanx but your example did not include "www. hotmail. com/a.php". Also im not interested in "www.this_i_dont_want.com" because its not inside the "<Div class".

Comment: did you want to extract `hotmail.com` from this string `http://www.hotmail.com/a.php?fdas` without using any `www` or `.com`?

Comment: yes. But also the examples with spaces. I know it sounds weird but there are spaces sometimes where i harvest.

Comment: So it's hard to done two things. One would be better.

Comment: sed is the right tool for this. You command would be `sed -nr 's/^.*www\.\s*([^\.]*\.)\s*([^\/]*).*/\1\2/p' file`. It extracts hotmail.com from `http://www.hotmail.com/a.php?fdas` and also from  `www. hotmail. com/a.php`